# how to add text information to avi by using directshow

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directshow

thanks to click my question.

To make mux stream avi video, I had using directshow avimux filter.
But, directshow avimux filter is only use to media/img files.
How can I add text information to avi file and meet the stream mux(audio+video+text) condition?

Answer (score 0):

[AVI Mux Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is built on top of AVI API and is limited to support video, audio and DV interleaved streams. Hence, no text option.

> Input Pin Media Types Any major type that corresponds to an old-style
>   FOURCC, or MEDIATYPE_AUXLine21Data. (For more information, see
>   FOURCCMap Class.)
>
> - If the major type is MEDIATYPE_Audio, the format must be FORMAT_WaveFormatEx.
> - If the major type is MEDIATYPE_Video, the format must be FORMAT_VideoInfo or FORMAT_DvInfo.
> - If the major type is MEDIATYPE_Interleaved, the format must be FORMAT_DvInfo.

To embed text as an additional stream, you need to write a custom filter (on top of either Windows AVI API, or FFmpeg or other) or find an appropriate third party replacement for stock AVI multiplexer.